# Google Map from database

Tags: asp-classic, google-maps-api-3

I am looking for some example to use google map for using in ASP MS Access. I need it for address listing , so map will get data from database.

Building no,
Street no.,
City,
Code,
Country

Answer (score 0):

You can store address in your database as actual address string. Like

`1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA`

And when generating Google Map for it on a webpage - use [Geocoding](http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/). Also you can store latitude and longtitude (maybe also as strings) for some addresses that will not be found (or found incorrectly / not precisely) through Geocoding.

PS. I am not an ASP dev. I work with mere PHP+MySQL, but thats how I used to store addresses for Google Maps on one tourist website project.